# { "error": "server_error", "error_description": "Internal Server Error" }

Tags: jpa, jwt, spring-security

Estoy haciendo un programa con spring oracle jpa hibernate y al querer generar el token con informacion adicional me da este error: **{     "error": "server_error",     "error_description": "Internal Server Error" }**

Esta es la parte en la que agrego la info adicional

```
@Component
public class InfoAdicToken implements TokenEnhancer{

    @Autowired
    private IUsuarioService usuarioService;
    
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        
        Usuario usuario= usuarioService.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
        Map<String, Object> info = new HashMap<>();
        info.put("Info adicional", "Hola: ".concat(authentication.getName()));
        
        info.put("nombre adicional: ", usuario.getUsername());
        System.out.println(info);
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken)accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(info);
        return accessToken;
    }
    
    
}
```

Este es mi codigo en la parte que genero eltoken con info adicional

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(infoAdicToken,accessTokenConverter()));
     
       endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
               .tokenStore(tokenStore())
               .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
               .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
               ;
      
    }
```

Comment: Sin ver los logs con el error exacto que te da, es imposible saber qué está pasando. Lo que has puesto en pantalla es un error http que se produce cuando el servidor ha fallado, nada más

Comment: 2020-12-11 17:15:39.995  WARN 5752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.o.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint  : Handling error: NullPointerException, null
2020-12-11 17:15:39.998  WARN 5752 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [java.lang.NullPointerException]

Comment: eso me sale en consola del spring

Comment: Te recomiendo que edites la pregunta para añadir la información. Por cierto, si te está dando un NullPointerExceptio es porque estás intentando trabajar con un objeto que está a null. Te recomiendo que te asegures de que todo con lo que trabajas está correctamente asignado y no es null, por ejemplo, es muy común que falle el `findByUsername(authentication.getName());` y te esté devolviendo `null`, pero como no lo controlas, peta :)